# Apache timeout for NFS unavailablity

Tags: apache-2.2

Id like to ask, is there anyway to set a timeout for a hung filesystem.

For example, if NFS has become stale or having an issue of what ever sort (this is not about tweaking NFS, im more interested in tweaking apache), apache has the problem whereby the load climbs through the roof.

Id like to curb that.

Ive looked at

EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile

But I would like to more ways of tweaking apache.

Thanks
Brent

Comment: Fix the problem where it occurs, don't try to paper around it by adding needless complexity to the wrong layer.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, the solution you are looking for is in another castle.

If NFS mount (or whatever filesystem your document root is on) stops responding, Apache *will* be in deep trouble, no amount of Apache tuning helps in that.

You need to concentrate on monitoring those events so you receive e-mail/sms/some other message in case of those troubles. And, if NFS is problematic, fix that somehow or switch to some other method for your document root needs.

Answer (score 2):

I know you say you want to tweak Apache, not NFS. The issue is that any process, Apache or anything else, that is blocking on disk IO will simply never return.

In the case of NFS, you can actually control this behavior at the mount point. Take a look at `man nfs`.

If your NFS server is `hard` mounted, if the server ever stops responding, the client will wait indefinitely for a response. The result is your Apache process will hang. `hard` mounts are almost always a preference if you are writing over the mount point and you care about your data (you want the process writing the data to know if/when it ever completed).

If your NFS server is `soft` mounted then the client may eventually return even if the NFS server is totally borked. Use this in conjunction with the `timeo` NFS mount option to specify the retransmission timeout.

If you have many processes in the run queue or blocking on IO, as you said, you load will climb very high. Allowing slow or hung NFS operations to timeout via a `soft` mount would mitigate that. However, you'll still want to devise a way to gracefully propagate those failures to the client.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I was thinking of tuning  net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time = 300 and
net/ipv4/tcp_max_orphans=1000 to maybe help.